# In Excel 2013, Import Text Wizard, is there a way to have multiple "Other" values?

Tags: microsoft-excel, copy-paste, import

I am using Paste/Import Text Wizard to get some output from another program into a spreadsheet.  There are several standard choices for delimiters such as space, comma, semicolon and tab.  There is also an "Other" check box with a text field next to it which allows entry of an unlisted delimiter.  However, I want to have 2 "Other" delimiters, but can't find a way for it to take.  The text box appears to accept a single character and there is no other way I can see to enter a second user-defined delimiter.  Is this possible?

Comment: Are the delimiters next to each other, or at different places?

Comment: Different places

Comment: And they are both not part of the ones you can put checkmarks next to, right?

Comment: Correct, two delimiters not listed among the standard choices

Comment: I think you might need to find and replace them outside of excel or use VBA inside excel. Depending on where they are, you might use one in import and then the other with text to columns.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Power Query Add-In for this.  It can first split columns using a single delimiter (I would use your most-common delimiter), using the Get External Data / From File / From Text button.  Then you can Edit the Query definition, select each of the columns that still need to be split and clicking Split Column / By Delimiter.

The Query then becomes a reliable, automated process you can repeat on any new file, by Refreshing the Query. Power Query can also handle many other common data transformation requirements.

Comment: I've loaded the add in and am playing around with it.  Just curious, can you get external data from clipboard instead of all those other sources like file?  That would be my most likely use case.  What I have tried so far is 1) Import Text Wizard followed by 2) Excel Data From Table.

Comment: No direct option for that.  The easiest would be to paste into an Excel table (in the current workbook) and then from the Power Query ribbon choose "From Table".  To update in the future, paste again into the same table (optionally deleting old rows first), then Refresh the Power Query.